# How to receive XMLHTTPRequests on Server side?

Tags: apache, nginx, server, xmlhttprequest, web-hosting

it's probably I pretty dumb question but I just can't find any information online on how to do this. Probably I'm googling the wrong stuff.

I have to do 2 things. Send xml files via XMLHTTPRequests to a given Server. That's not a problem and easily done. But the company I'm working with also wants me to provide a Server that can receive XMLHTTPRequests and saves them into a file which I can then work with.

How do I handle this? Does I have to setup e.g. NGINX to do this or is this just a specific website I have to host? When I google for XMLHTTPRequests I only find how to send or get data but not how to setup the Server Side. I really have no clue.

Hope you can send me the right way so I can finally continue to work on this.

ty :)

Comment: on the server, you receive a request. No need for differentiation or handle any differently than any other http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web server server side to receive requests from `XMLHTTPRequest` calls.  You could set up NGINX to do this, or use any web server that you want.

This isn't usually covered in the documentation because you need to serve the page that contains the JavaScript with the `XMLHTTPRequest` from some server. To get to the point where you are making a `XMLHTTPRequest`, you already need some HTTP server set up and working.  You would usually configure the page to be served from some a main URL like `https://example.com/` and have the `XMLHTTPRequest` call to another URL like `https://example.com/log-data` would have you logic for storing to a file like your requirement.